# Autohotkey, SoundSet: Toggle volume to 2% with function key (Windows XP)

Tags: audio, toggle, autohotkey, mute

I reached a dead end with my noob research re the SoundSet command. I'd appreciate a script or a pointer.

I don't know how to make this command toggle:

F11::SoundSet, 2

I can see how to make master mute toggle - but not this 'mostly mute' to 2% level (for muting ads while monitoring for a show to come back on). Thanks.

(Note: this for Windows XP if that's relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F11::
    if (muting) {
        SoundSet, %oldVolume%
        muting := false
    }
    else {
        SoundGet, oldVolume
        SoundSet, 2
        muting := true
    }    
return
```

Basically, you create a variable `muting` so your script can recall which state it's in. When you hit F11, it checks if `muting` is true or not. If it is, then it will set the system volume to `oldVolume`, and then set `muting` to false. If `muting` is false, then it will save the current volume as `oldVolume`, set the system volume to 2, and then set `muting` to true.

Comment: Thank you; exactly what I need and I understand the basic syntax.